# IE being stubborn with a drop up/down menu

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, html

I have a drop up/down menu located at http://islandicecream.sitesbyjoe.com (this is a site I'm building). I'm at the fun part where I test all the IE versions and get them working as best I can.

The particular trouble I'm having is getting IE to make the links in the drop down span 100% of their parent container. I feel like I've tried everything and it still won't behave.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes.. post some code, make it easier on us if you want our help ;) CSS / html / what you tried, what the exact issue is, etc.

Comment: I just tested it with IE Tab 2 and there doesn't seem to be any problem, it looks the same in IE as FF (minus the rounded corners). What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: The only differences I can find is that in IE there is a pink border around the menu items and no rounded corners in IE7. And I presume the rounded corners are because of CSS3 which won't work in IE below version 9. As for the border you need to set the property `border: none;` for all `li` under `ul class="sub_nav"`.

Comment: Yes, the pink borders are supposed to be there. I've placed the borders so you can see the elements that are being bad. In FF the menu links span 100% of the dropdown menu, but in IE they shrink to the size of the text in the link. width: 100% !important; doesn't fix it either - it's weird.

Comment: On posting code, looking at the url I posted ( http://islandicecream.sitesbyjoe.com) with firebug on will let you see things faster than me posting hundreds of lines of HTML and CSS in this case, no?

Comment: No problem in IE8 the menu links span the whole width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. You need to specify a width for `#nav ul.sub_nav`. Since there is no width specified to that element, its children don't know what 100% means. Well at least that is the case in IE7.

Comment: @sitesbyjoe, it is always easy to miss something as simple as that. You could have also specified the width for the `a` tags and that would have worked too.